# VBox vhd to vdi conversion

Tags: virtualbox

I have a VHD file in D drive named "Ubuntu VM1.vhd" i am trying to convert if to vdi , i coem across the clonehd command with --format vdi parameter ,i dont understand why it is giving the invalid parameter error..i tried with several changes but its giving the same..is there any other way to convert vhd to vdi...

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonehd D:\Ubuntu VM1.vh
d D:\UbuntuServer1.vdi --format vdi
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.1.2
(C) 2005-2011 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage clonehd          <uuid>|<filename> <uuid>|<outputfile>
                            [--format VDI|VMDK|VHD|RAW|<other>]
                            [--variant Standard,Fixed,Split2G,Stream,ESX]
                            [--existing]


Syntax error: Invalid parameter 'D:\UbuntuServer1.vdi'
```

Comment: Cross link to the same question on superuser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/179271/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-vhd-images-to-vdi-images

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try:
    VBoxManage.exe clonehd "D:\Ubuntu VM1.vhd" D:\UbuntuServer1.vdi --format vdi

Comment: C:\>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonehd "D
:\Ubuntu VM1.vhd" D:\UbuntuServer1.vdi --format vdi

Comment: I am seeing `Unexpected token 'clonehd' in expression or statement.` in PowerShell Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I was using linux RHEL OS and it seems that suggestion @user3549168 gave which quite worked for me pretty well. I did some modification however. The command worked for me that convert **vhd to vdi** is while I was in the folder vhd file exists:

```
sudo vboxmanage clonehd inputFileName.vhd outputFileName.vdi --format vdi
```

Command in practical use:

```
sudo vboxmanage clonehd window.vhd window23.vdi --format vdi
```

Answer (score -6):

exmple work

```
cd C:\Program Files\Oracle VM VirtualBox entre
```

VBoxManage clonehd "`L:\Java\Achraf Rida\W7-64.vhd" "L:\Java\Achraf Rida\W7-64.vdi`" --format vdi

peu etre 
Try: `VBoxManage.exe clonehd "D:\Ubuntu\VM1.vhd" "D:\Ubuntu\Server1.vdi" --format vdi`